# Change actual font color based on another cell value in the Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I currently have a worksheet that looks into column B and matches the string with a String in Column Z then changes the color of the matching String to font.color in column B. The problem is that column B is colored by conditional formatting so the code is unrecognized. I need to be able to have the actual font color change in column B when the condtion is true. In addition, the code would need to be incremented until the last row of the sheet is reach.

Here's the current conditional formats I have setup

> Blockquote

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Story",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format dark blue
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Requirement",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format green
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EPIC",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format red
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Test",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format teal
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("New Feature",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format orange
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Theme",Template!D5))=TRUE 'format gray
```

> Blockquote

```
Sub Main()
  Call NoLinks
  Call SetCellWarning
  Call colortext
End Sub

Sub NoLinks()
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete
End Sub

Sub SetCellWarning()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range, rSetColumn As Range

    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    Set rSetColumn = Range(Cells(5, 26), Cells(iLastRow, 26)) ' Column "Z"...

    For Each cel In rSetColumn
        If cel.Value = "" Then
            With cel
                cel.Value = "NOT MAPPED"
            End With
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub

***'The colortext runs but does not update unless the font color is manually updated***    
Sub colortext()
start_row = 5
key_col = 2
linked_col = 26
i = start_row 'start on row one
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, key_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    o = start_row 'start with row one for second column
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(o, linked_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    If Not InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)) = 0 Then  'if cell    contents found in cell
        With Cells(o, linked_col).Characters(Start:=InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)), Length:=Len(Cells(i, key_col))).Font
            .Color = Cells(i, key_col).Font.Color  'change color of this part of the cell
        End With
    End If
    o = o + 1 'increment the cell in second column
    Loop
    i = i + 1 'increment the cell in the first column
Loop
End Sub
```

> Blockquote

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. Why do you have conditional formatting on column B if you want to control the color? Or do you want to "turn off conditional formatting on certain cells if specific conditions are met"? Can you please clarify?

Comment: This was a lesson learned the hard way. I need to get rid of the conditional formatting for column B and have VBA to change the actual colors based on the same conditions. For instance, If D5=requirement then the B5 fontcolor = green, if D5=EPIC then B5 font color =red, D5=story then B5 blue. Once the code has run for B5 I need to do the same for the remaining rows. The conditional formatting does this but does not actually change the color of font.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the right color number with in you statement?

Comment: "The conditional formatting does this but does not actually change the color of font" - is the problem that your code isn't working, or that the conditional formatting isn't working? In the conditional formatting formula you give, nothing references the value in column B, nor does it perform a lookup in column Z... So - do you actually want working VBA code, or do you want help fixing the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you simply want "the solution you tried before" to work, here is how you get the conditional formatting working:

1. Select the cells (in column B) to which you want to apply the conditional formatting
2. Click on "conditional formatting" button. Clear any rules you no longer want, then create a "new rule" based on "an equation being true"
3. Enter the following equation: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1, "EPIC"))`
4. Select the format you want for cells with the text "EPIC" in them (note - with this order of "SEARCH", we look for the text in B1 to be contained in the phrase "EPIC", so "E" will match, as will "IC". If you want only cells with "That was EPIC" to be matched, you need to reverse the order of the arguments
5. Add more rules for the other words you want to match, and the color you need

This is what the dialog looks like when you have just created a single rule:

[image]

And this is what the "conditional formatting" dialog looks like after you have completed the second rule (in my example, I applied these rules to 8 cells):

[image]

At this point, the spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

This seems to be what you were asking for... if it's not, then please clarify in the comments!

Comment: Thanks Floris. I currently have the conditional formatting you provided in place. The problem is that the formatting does not change the actual font color only the appearance in the cell.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. How do you tell the difference between "the actual font color" and "the appearance" - and why do you care about the difference? I think that if I understand the answer to that question I can give you a better solution.

Comment: If you add a conditonal format to change the text color in a cell then you open the cell format screen (right-click cell>format cels...) you'll notice the actual color does not update. So my code to match the cell color only recognizes the color in the cell format and not the coditional format.

Comment: Ah... you are using the "font color" as a _tag_ to do something else - and since the "font color" property didn't change, you can't see that the conditional formatting "did anything". Is that it?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to correct this by using a Case statement but it does seem to be working correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the conditional formatting is easy:

```
If (Cells(i, key_col).FormatConditions.Count > 0) Then
    Cells(i, key_col).FormatConditions.Delete 
End If
.Color = Cells(i, key_col).Font.Color  'change color of this part of the cell
```

You can even store it in a `FormatCondition` variable and apply to the cell later if you wish.

Comment: I'm not too sure this is going to work. I have conditional formatting setup to change the "color" based on the text for column B and D. In column B, the conditon checks column D, same row, and if text is found changes the color. Both scenarios do not change the actual font color which renders my code useless. Now I need to outline each color based on the text. So 7 different text entries would equal different colors. If one of the text entries is found in the row, the second cell of that row will change to the respective color.

Comment: @user2642587 in one of the previous versions of your question (now, I think that this bit is not anymore) I read that you were looking for a way to avoid the Conditional Formatting to be applied to certain cells; that's why I posted this answer. I haven't analysed your exact requirements in detail (to be honest I am not even sure why you have a Conditional Formatting which you don't want to apply). I will take a more detailed look at your exact problem and come back to you on this.

Comment: @user2642587 after reading the conditions/comments a bit better I am more confused: you are saying that the conditions proposed by Floris are not working in your spreadsheet? Also I am not quite following the point you want to make in your comment: the proposed code makes sure that the color in the given cell is the one you want independently upon having a conditional formatting in this cell or not.

Comment: If you take a look at the colortext routine it searches the string in Z for a match to a string in B then changes the color of the string in Z. Since conditional formatting does not change the actual font color nothing changes because by default all colors are automatic (black). So I removed the conditional formatting for column B (all black). Now I need multiple text values found in D$ to equal a font color. Then based on the row if the one of those text values is found, change the color of the issue number. This will continue until an empty cell in B is reached

Answer (score 0):

Here's the winning solution:

```
Sub colorkey()

start_row = 5
key_col = 2
flag_col = 4

i = start_row 'start on row one

Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, key_col)) 'Do until empty cell

Tval = Cells(i, flag_col).Value
Select Case Tval
Case "Requirement"
    'cval = green
    cVal = 10
Case "New Feature"
    'cval = orange
    cVal = 46
Case "Test"
    'cval = lt blue
    cVal = 28
Case "Epic"
    'cval = red
    cVal = 3
Case "Story"
    'cval = dk blue
    cVal = 49
Case "Theme"
    'cval = grey
    cVal = 48
Case "NOT MAPPED"
    'cval = Maroon
    cVal = 53
End Select
Cells(i, key_col).Font.ColorIndex = cVal

i = i + 1 'increment the row
Loop

End Sub
```